# How to change the title alignment just for the appendix sections?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, appendices

I am formatting my dissertation document using the [`usfdis`](http://dalamagkidis.info/miscellanea/usfdis/) class. However, due to new specifications, the appendices titles should now be single spaced and aligned to the left margin.

The code referred to the appendix section in the `usfdis.cls` is the following:

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{% Appendices have a cover page and different
                     % layout
\clearpage
\vspace*{0.6in}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Appendices}}
 \begin{center}{\chpsformat Appendices\par}
 \end{center}
\newpage
\addtolength{\textheight}{-2\baselineskip+3pt} %<--- Weird 3.5pt
\setlength{\headsep}{2\baselineskip-3pt}%            it's magic!
\ch@ngetext
\gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname }%
\gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapter}
{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain}\@afterindentfalse\secdef\@appendix\@schapter}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}%
\setcounter{section}{0}%
\makeatletter
\let\@oddhead\@empty
\def\@oddhead{\vbox{\chapalign\chpformat (continued) } }
\makeatother

}
```

One option is to put the appendices as sections instead of chapters and then they are going to be aligned to the left but I need also to have the section titles as for example:

> ```
> Appendix A: Name of Appendix A
> Appendix B: Name of Appendix B
> etc.
> ```

The picture below is an example to show what the new requirements are:

[image: New format requirements]

The code below is an example of the actual format of the document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,doublespacing,alignheadcenter]{usfdis}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Disertation title}
\author{The author}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\department{Department}
\college{Engineering}
\advisor{Main advisor}
\member{Member 1, Ph.D. \and Member2, Ph.D. \and Member3, Ph.D.}
\approvaldate{ 2013}
\copyrightdate{2013}
\keywords{keyword 1\and keyword 2}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
\maketitle  

\chapter{Introduction}   
 \section{Section 1.1 in Chapter 1}

 \chapter{Conclusions} 
 \clearpage

\appendix
 \chapter{Copyright Approvals for Appendices A, B and C, respectively }
 \noappendix

 \begin{bio} bio information
 \end{bio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class file is quite well designed and therefore relatively simple to modify.  Add the following to your document preamble. I've made a new command `\appalign` to align the heading of the appendix only and then redefined the internal command that makes the heading use that command instead of the class `\chapalign`.  Although the value could be hard coded, this change would be a better way to incorporate it into the class, especially if the Graduate School could change their minds again, as they are wont to do.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appalign}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\@makeapphead}[1]{%
\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}{\appalign%
{\chpformat #1}%
\par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Here's the full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,doublespacing,alignheadcenter]{usfdis}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[plain]{fancyref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\appalign}{\raggedright}
\renewcommand{\@makeapphead}[1]{%
\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}{\appalign%
{\chpformat #1}%
\par\nobreak\vspace*{\baselineskip}}%
}
\makeatother
\title{Disertation title}
\author{The author}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\department{Department}
\college{Engineering}
\advisor{Main advisor}
\member{Member 1, Ph.D. \and Member2, Ph.D. \and Member3, Ph.D.}
\approvaldate{ 2013}
\copyrightdate{2013}
\keywords{keyword 1\and keyword 2}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}
\maketitle  

\chapter{Introduction}   
 \section{Section 1.1 in Chapter 1}

 \chapter{Conclusions} 
 \clearpage

\appendix
 \chapter{Copyright Approvals for Appendices A, B and C, respectively }
 \noappendix

 \begin{bio} bio information
 \end{bio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that!, it works very well. I really appreciate your help (I cannot up vote your answer since I need more reputation, tough)

Comment: You're welcome. People will probably upvote your question a bit more and you'll have enough reputation to upvote. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: just a quick question. How can I make the appendices titles single spaced as stated in the original question?

Comment: If it's ok that the second line is aligned flush with the left margin (not a hanging indent) then you can just add `\singlespacing` to the `\appalign` definition.